# Android - when creating bitmap of screen view big emoji got disappears

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I am creating editable image which have feature to add text on it.
After adding text big size emojis disappears from text when creating bitmap of view.
can anybody suggest any solution of it ?

Comment: You need to share your code snippet so others can see & investigate what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by setting

textView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);